# What is meaning of "I was ten"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

"I was ten years old"
What is the meaning of the above sentence??
Does it mean that I was ten years and my eleventh year is running? or I am 10 years completed?

Comment: You were in your eleventh  year: you had passed your tenth birthday and had not yet reached your eleventh birthday.

Comment: Your alternates mean the same thing. If you were ten years completed then you must be running in your eleventh year. Or do you mean to imply that you think it possible to say "I was ten years old" to refer to any time after the 10th anniversary of your birth, e.g. when you were actually 17? Also I'm curious to know why you ask the question. Are you coming from a language/culture where age is counted differently?

Comment: @toandfro In some places you're counted as 1 when you're born.

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

- In your **first** year of life you are **zero** years old;
- In your **second** year of life you are **one** year old;
- In your **third** year of life you are **two** years old;

And so on.  If someone says "I was ten years old", they're referring to a time when they were in their eleventh year of life.

(Note that people rarely say "zero years old"; instead, they usually talk about younger children in smaller units such as weeks or months.  People also rarely say things like "in my eleventh year of life"; instead, they say things like "when I was ten years old".)

Comment: Though I've seen forms that ask for age of family members that say things like, "If a child is under one year old, enter zero."